# Octave compute taylor series of exponential function

Tags: octave, series, factorial, exponential

I have a problem in Octave to solve but I can't get to beat it.

I have to compute the taylor series of the exponential function with x=1 and the factorial has to be an extra function (self defined).

My solution I have found recently:

This is factorial function to compute factorial.

```
function answer = factorial(n)
  if(n<0)
    error("no definition for negative factorial");
  endif

  answer=1;

  if(n==0)
    return;
  else
    for i=2:n
        answer = answer*i;
    endfor
  endif
endfunction
```

This is Taylor function with factorial function included

```
function answer = taylor(n)
 answer = 1 ./ factorial(n)
endfunction
```

Now to my Problem:

When I call the sum of the taylor between 0 and 5 (for example)

```
sum taylor([0:5])
```

then I get the solution of 1

```
answer =  1
ans =  1
```

It solves for every step a number of 1 and at the end it shows 1 which isn't correct.
The correct answer would be 2.7182 for e.
There is sth wrong in my code.
Are you know how to beat that taylor series that I can get the correct answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `taylor` definition takes 1 argument, you're passing 2. You should get an error.

Comment: I have correct it in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have beaten the Taylor series exponential function problem. :-)
Here my solution. The output is a bit strange at the moment but correct.

```
function answer = taylor(n)
answer = 0
  for i = 0:n
    erg = 1^i / factorial(i)
    answer = answer + erg
  end
endfunction
```

jo

```
function answer = factorial(n)
  if(n<0)
    error("no definition for negative factorial");
  endif

  answer=1;

  if(n==0)
    return;
  else
    for i=2:n
        answer = answer*i;
    endfor
  endif
endfunction
```

At the end only call "taylor(5)" for example and it should compute "e"

Answer (score 1):

There's already a factorial function defined in Octave. It returns a vector if you input a vector, so:

```
octave:1> factorial(0:6)
ans =
     1     1     2     6    24   120   720
```

If you really **must** define your own factorial function, then you should write it vectorized. If so, you can obtain the desired result with simply:

```
sum(1./factorial(0:20))
ans =  2.71828182845905
```